# XAMPP-VM Object not found

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xampp-vm

I am new to XAMPP, so I'm still not 100% on what I'm doing. I have a 11-inch MacBook Air (early 2015). I've tried everything below both with Safari v12.0 and Chrome 29.0.3497.100.

I downloaded XAMPP-VM 7.2.11 and ran it (without changing any config files). After enabling port forwarding localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH), I am able to get "localhost:8080/phpmyadmin" OR "192.168.64.2/phpmyadmin" to show my databases and such.
[image: localhost:8080/phpmyadmin]
... and I can do the same on Chrome.

However, here's what I get when I try to access *anything* else from opt/lampp on Safari. I've tried accessing everything with "localhost:8080/opt/lampp/...", "localhost:8080/...", "192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/...", and "192.168.64.2/...":
[image: localhost:8080/myApp/index.php]

Chrome is **only** different when I try "192.168.64.2/icons", where I see a file explorer type view:
[image: Chrome 192.168.64.2/icons]

This appears to be the icons folder "opt/lampp/icons".

I have tried making several changes to the config files since, exactly according to numerous recommended solutions for both Windows and MacOS, but I do not remember what all I did and upon discovering that each did solution not work, I reverted the changes back to original. I've also tried reinstalling 3 times, to no avail.

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Ignore the port forwarding if you are using `locahost` as you are not coming in through your router. Just use `localhost` as internally Apache is listening on port 80 if your port forwarding is correctly described

Comment: If I do not enable port forwarding, I get a no connection error by using `localhost/phpmyadmin`. I can, however, still do that with `192.168.64.2/phpmyadmin`. That could be a config setting, since I remember at some point in my experimentation being able to use `localhost`.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. I tried to access a PHP application that I placed into `htdocs/`, it a fatal error was raised telling me that the required `require.php` couldn't be found. It was definitely in `/opt/lampp/`. I tried to access it directly in the browser, but can't remember what that did. But afterwards the application worked. It seemed as if the mount was not up-to-date somehow.